# array_rand returning incorrect value from array

Tags: php, arrays, random

I'm having a problem when using `array_rand`.

The thing is that I called some values from my database into an array, and then I did `array_rand` to randomly select one of those values (you don't say).

```
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM random");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $num[] = $row["id"];
}
```

If I do a `print_r($num);`, I get the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 6
    [6] => 7
    [7] => 8
    [8] => 9
    [9] => 10
    [10] => 11
    [11] => 12
    [12] => 13
    [13] => 14
)
```

But when doing `array_rand($num);`, one of the values that I randomly get is `0`, which as you can see, is not in the list, therefore the rest of the code that uses this random value won't work if it cames up with it.

I searched in Google for this problem, but couldn't find a solution, I'm sorry if this has been mentioned before.

Hopefully you can help me fix this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, why not use [`RAND()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand) in your query and save some work & resources?

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM random ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
$result = mysqli_fetch_object($query);
```

Comment: Yup, thanks. I'm kinda new to PHP + MySQL and I keep forgeting that I can do this stuff with MySQL.

Comment: @user2077474 I've only recently started getting comfortable with MySQL - I used to leave a lot up to PHP as well (anything other than basic sorting, joining data, etc). You'll be surprised by how much MySQL can be responsible for.

Answer (score 2):

As the document said, **[array_rand()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php)** returns the **key** for a random entry.

So you have to do with `$num[array_rand($num)]` to get the value.

Comment: Oh I see, any other function that I could use?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of [array_rand](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) (emphasis added):

> Picks one or more random entries out of an array, and returns the **key** (or keys) of the random entries.

0 is the key of your first element being returned